# How to insert decimal number into table and preserve 2 digits

Tags: postgresql, insert, decimal

While working with basic table operations (create, insert, select) on my PSQL server I noticed unexpected behavior. The decimal number which I insert seems to lose precision. Most likely a rookie error on my part, so I appreciate any feedback.

I would expect both base0 and base1 ending on .056 and after +1 operation result should be 40262.056

[image: Example of unexpected behavior]

Answer (score 0):

Replacing type "real" with "decimal(10,3)" seem to fix the issue

> create table test1 (eid int, base0 decimal(10,3), base1 decimal(10,3));

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/